# Google+ APIs and OAuth requests are being shutdown on March 7, 2019. What shall I consider as replacement for Google+ APIs and OAuth?

Tags: google-api, oauth

I have just received this message from GoogleDevelopers-noreply@google.com about the Google+ API I am using for a Web application:

> On March 7, 2019, all Google+ APIs and Google+ Sign-in will be shut
> down completely. This will be a progressive shutdown, with API calls
> starting to intermittently fail as early as January 28, 2019, and
> OAuth requests for Google+ scopes starting to intermittently fail as
> early as February 15, 2019.
>
> #### What do I need to do?
>
> Please **update your projects listed** below by March 7, 2019 and ensure
> they are no longer using Google+ APIs, or requesting Google+ OAuth
> scopes. The data below shows which Google+ API methods your projects
> have recently called, as well as Google+ OAuth scopes it has
> requested.

It is not clear what is the replacement for this. The goal is to still allow users to authenticate in my Web application using their Google account.

**Question:** What shall I consider as replacement for Google+ APIs and OAuth?

Comment: This is off-topic here as this site is about *using* web applications as end-users.

Comment: @Rubén - ok, I thought it is about using GooglePlus' Developer Console. However, I have flagged it to be migrated to Webmasters since it seems to be ontopic there (actually I have received this notification related to a Web application I have developed). Thanks.

Comment: I have flagged my question for it to be moved to Webmasters. Can anyone do this or should I directly write it there?